# Explain as though I'm five years old: Infinite Numbers but Finite Length

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> All natural numbers are finite in length.
>   The set of natural numbers is infinite.

The above is something that I accept as true, but something I don't understand. The argument I presented was:

> Given a set $X$ of n consecutive natural numbers starting from $1$, to $n$ the length (number of digits) of $n$ is $>= log(n)$.
>   If we take all the natural numbers $(\infty)$, the length of some number should be $log(\infty)$ which is?

I get that $log(n)$ is a (***much***) slower growing function than $n$, but I don't get what makes $n$ become infinite and $log(n)$ not? What is the limit if any on $log (n)$? It's something I find it difficult to wrap my head around.
 
For example, the harmonic series diverges to infinity, but $ln(n)$ provides an approximation for the harmonic series.
 
Why then does the harmonic series diverge to infinity, but length$(n)$ does not?

Comment: $\log n$ diverges to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, which is not even surprising: children, adults and machines have issues with big integers because *big integers are very long*. I don't understand why the part which begins with "For example" should be an example: I think it's just an unrelated fact you've heard somewhere and put it together with this.

Comment: "ELI5" is not a common abbreviation; I've edited the title accordingly.

Comment: "I don't get what makes n become infinite and log(n) not? "  $n$ does not become infinite.  $n$ is always a finite number.  "Why then does the harmonic series diverge to infinity, but length(n) does not"?  length (n) *DOES* diverge to infinity.  $length(n)$ and $n$ and $n^2$ and $e^n$ all diverge *to* infinity but *all* of the specific values are always finite.  You are confusing being infinite in number with being finite in value.  And this is true for $n$, not just for length.  But of for $n$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr

You are confusing "being infinite in value" with "being infinite in number", and being "finite in value" with "being bounded/converging".

length($n$) is absolutely no different than $n$ in either.

Both {length($n$)} and {$n$} are infinite in number.  Both length($n$) and $n$ are finite in value. And both length($n$) and $n$ diverge to infinity.

So ... "but I don't get what makes n become infinite and log(n) not?":  Answer $n$ does not become infinite.

"What is the limit if any on log(n)?" $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty} \log n = \infty$

"but ln(n) provides an approximation for the harmonic series"  $\ln (n)$ provides an approximation of a *partial* harmonic series: $\sum_\limits{i=1}^n \frac 1i \approx \ln (n)$. But  $\sum\limits_{i= 1}^{\infty} = \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_\limits{i=0}^n\frac 1i = \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln(n) = \infty$

"Why then does the harmonic series diverge to infinity, but length(n) does not?" Answer: length($n$) *does* diverge to infinity.

====

I think the issue of the *length* of a number is a misleading red herring.

Sure, the length of $n$ increases logrithmically slower than $n$ but .... that has nothing to do with it always being finite.  The *square* of all natural numbers increases geometrically *faster* than $n$ and the square of all natural numbers are always finite.

And *all* of those; the length of the numbers, the size of the numbers, and the squares of the numbers *all* are unbounded and *do* tend to infinity even though each log, square, and number is finite.

The issue is how can there be a set of things that are each finite, but the set  has an infinite *number* of them.

And if you think about it, there really is no issue.  How many things are in the group have nothing to do with anything about the things in the group.  A set of seven objects has seven things in it, whether those things are atoms, dustspecks, elephants, galaxies, or universes.

I suppose the confusion comes down to when   and everything that can be counted has a representative number and every number is finite, how can you count to something infinite. Or perhaps more accurately, how can you *not* count to something infinite if everything you have is finite.

I think the easiest explanation is the most common one.  "What is the largest number? Now add one to that."  Every number is finite but for every number there are more numbers larger than it.  Each one is finite but there is no limit to all of them as a group and the group is infinitely large.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the natural numbers *does* diverge as you go towards infinity. However, if you select a given natural number (regardless of how big it is), its length must be finite. Remember that infinity is not a natural number. Note that saying that all natural numbers have finite length is different from saying that the length of the natural numbers is bounded (which is not true).

If the set of natural numbers is finite, then we must have some natural number with a (finite) maximal length. But, because we can write a natural number with length at least as big as $\log(n)$ for any $n$ (such as $10^{\log(n)+1}$), and as $\log(n)$ diverges to infinity as $n\to \infty$, the maximum length is not finite and is therefore never achieved on the set of natural numbers, so the set of natural numbers cannot be finite.